# Parsing operation without prefix in Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to parse a simple language with Parsec. There can either be assignments "x=y" or prefixed stuff like "prefix test". However, the parsing rule for assignments is greedy and does not fail if there is no "=". For example,

```
parse tp "" "prefix foo"
```

leads to a parsing error. The corresponding code:

```
module Test where
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Language
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Expr
import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Token as P

lexer = haskell
reserved   = P.reserved lexer
reservedOp = P.reservedOp lexer

data Term = Term String
  deriving (Show)

term :: Parser Term
term = do { x <- many alphaNum
          ; reservedOp "="
          ; y <- many alphaNum
          ; return (Term (x++y))
          }
   <|> do { reserved "prefix"
          ; x <- many alphaNum
          ; return (Term x)
          }

tp = do { e<-term; return e }
```

What am I missing? Is my approach even possible, or did I misunderstand Parsec?

Comment: How about inserting `spaces` after `reserved "prefix"`?

Comment: We never come this far, the parser only looks in the first do. If we change the order of the rules, the statement is correctly parsed. This only works in this simple case though, if we have more rules like the first one, the trick does not work anymore.

Comment: It doesn't work because `many alphaNum` consumes "prefix" but then fails - once a parser has failed after consuming input, it will not try another alternative (given by `<|>` or `choice`, etc). You need a `try` on the first parser. (I think you have misunderstood parsec - you are expecting automatic backtracking, but parsec simply doesn't do this. There are other parser libraries which do, I believe)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by user2407038 in the comments, the problem is that `x <- many alphaNum` consumes `prefix` and thus, the second rule cannot be applied. The solution is to put `try` in front of the block, this rewinds consumed parts of the stream.